# How to pass data from client to server in blazor hosted application

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-client-side

I need to pass a data from client side to server side in a blazor hosted application but I can't achieve this.

```
<button @onclick="PassData">Click me to send the data</button>

private async void PassData()
    {

        await Http.SendJsonAsync(HttpMethod.Post, "/api/Controller/Method", JsonObject);
    }
```

This method doesn't hit in my controller in server. Can you please help what i am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you map route to controller

```cs
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute(); // this line

                endpoints.MapFallbackToClientSideBlazor<Client.Startup>("index.html");
            });
```

Create a new controller into controllers folder

```cs
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class TestController : ControllerBase
    { 
         [HttpPost]
         public string Post([FromBody]Data data)
         {
            // Handle here
         }
    }
```

Call it

```cs
Http.PostJsonAsync<Data>("api/Test", data);
```

Hope it helps